# Avoid adding duplicate entry in iPhone contacts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, contacts

After adding an entry in iPhone contacts successfully, now I want to restrict the application to add the same entry again. (As it makes another entry in iPhone Contacts with same data).

Any simple way to accomplish this? or any work around?

Comment: only way is - search and match..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any simple way to accomplish this? or any work around?

Unless I misunderstand what you're trying to do, the simple solution would seem to be searching the contacts for the information that you're about to add. If you find the same data, don't add it again. If you find something similar, such as a contact with the same name, ask the user if they want to create another contact with that name or update the existing one.

Comment: Any other alternate?? I mean if user clicks again and again (say 100 times)on "Add to Contact" button, then we have to search and compare all the entries(which can be more than 1000) in contacts, everytime???

Comment: If you use `ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName()` it shouldn't be difficult to find just those people in the database with a matching name. Who cares how many times the user taps the "add" button -- it's a *computer*, and it won't complain if you ask it to do the same thing a million times. You only have to write the code once, right? If you're concerned, add some code to detect multiple attempts to add the same person and provide some feedback explaining that the contact already exists.